# Run list of SQL queries using conditions from range of cell values

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to run a list of SQL queries where a condition exists for "code" and the values sit in a range of cells on another sheet (from cells A2 to A385).

I have the code below, however, I get an invalid object name for SQLQueries!$A2:A385

So, I understand the syntax is not correct but I'm struggling to find the correct one regardless of reading numerous articles.

```
Sub RunSQLQueries()

'Select SQLQueries sheet
    Sheets("SQLQueries").Activate

'Initializes variables
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String

'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=HOSTNAME; Initial Catalog=DBNAME; UID=domain\user; Integrated Security=SSPI"

'Opens connection to the database
    cnn.Open ConnectionString

'Timeout
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

'Build SQK queries
    StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code IN (SELECT * FROM [SQLQueries!$A2:A385])"

'Performs the queries
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

'Select Results sheet
    Sheets("Results").Activate

'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell A2 of the active sheet
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

End Sub
```

The result I'm expecting is for a SQL query to be run using each condition from the range of values with the results being populated on the "Results" sheet from cells A2 down

Answer (score 0):

The query string is literally sent to the database server, and since your sql attempts to refer to an excel list that the server cannot access it returns an error. The server is looking for a table named [SQLQueries!$A2:A385]

To stick with your current plan, you will need to pass the  the IN () clause literally or by vba variable that is formatted as such:
 IN ( 'item1', 'item2' ...)

Note:You can remove single quotes if the items are numeric

I advise rethinking the plan by either
1) if it is possible to adjust things in the database side: Can you create a new reference table  to join to the actual table or create a view that only returns desired rows?  Then you would need a job that tweaks the filtering view/ table before running the query. The idea being you would not need to adjust the query each time bc a constant sql string would return the rows you need
Or
2) if the source table has say 100k rows or less,  and data is not too wide,  just select all the rows into excel in a new sheet, then filter that sheet (add a new column in excel that returns true using vlookup against your reference sheet) or use vlookup on your reference sheet to pull the desired columns

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

```
StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code IN (" & _
             InList(Sheets("SQLQueries").Range("A2:A385"),True) & ")"
```

Function to create a SQL "in" list given a range:

```
Function InList(rng As Range, quoted As Boolean)
    Dim qt, a, r As Long, c As Long, rv As String, v, sep As String
    a = rng.Value
    qt = IIf(quoted, "'", "")
    For r = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        v = Trim(a(r, c))
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            rv = rv & sep & qt & v & qt
            sep = ","
        End If
    Next c
    Next r
    InList = rv
End Function
```

Notes:

- Pass `False` as the second argument if you have numeric values
- I wouldn't use this for very large lists
- Be very certain you're not at risk from possible SQL injection issues: parameterized queries are always preferable but do not work with "in" lists